# Appending lots of HTML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

In trying to make a single-page site, I've gotten into the habit of using jQuery's `.append` function quite a bit. However, I'm sure there must be some better way of appending large blocks of code (for items such as tables, graphs, etc.) to a page. For instance, here's a hideous block from an AJAX response:

```
  $.ajax({
    data: {
        'cmd': 'rating',
        'api' : target
    },
    url: "api/feedback.php",
    global: false,
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
            document.getElementById("swagger-ui-container").innerHTML = "";
            var formElement = '<form class="form-horizontal"> <div class="form-group"> <label class="control-label col-md-12 title" for="title" style="padding-top:4vh; padding-bottom: 4vh"><h1 align="center">' + target + ' feedback form</h1></label> </div> <div class="form-group"> <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="name">Name:</label> <div class="col-md-9"> <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Please enter your name."> </input> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="email">Email:</label> <div class="col-md-9"> <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Please enter your email address."> </input> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="comments">Comments:</label> <div class="col-md-9"> <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="comments" placeholder="Please enter your comments."></textarea> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="rating" style="padding-top: 1.3vh">Please rate this API <br/>(click the stars):</label> <div class="col-md-9"> <div class="stars"> <form action=""> <input class="star star-5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star"/> <label class="star star-5" for="star-5"></label> <input class="star star-4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star"/> <label class="star star-4" for="star-4"></label> <input class="star star-3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star"/> <label class="star star-3" for="star-3"></label> <input class="star star-2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star"/> <label class="star star-2" for="star-2"></label> <input class="star star-1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star"/> <label class="star star-1" for="star-1"></label> Current Rating: ' + response[0]['rating'] + '</form> </div> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-9"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-bottom: 5vh">Submit a Review</button> </div> </div> </form>';
            document.getElementById("swagger-ui-container").innerHTML = formElement;
            console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Is there a better way to manage blocks like this without resorting to using lots of `.append` calls?

Comment: Do you mean append() or innerHTML?

Comment: Google for "jquery templating library".

Comment: instead of using all those inline elements, you can create them on the page then use jquery's .clone() to clone the elements.

Comment: @The One and Only ChemistryBlob
Either one for my use. If using one is preferable to the other, or if mixing them is discouraged, please let me know.

Comment: Just wanted to add that this is probably the best question I've ever seen asked on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

You can create the element in your HTML and hide it, and use it as a template. with `clone`, and then add the response's data at the right place.

For example:

```
<div id="templates" style="display: none;">
    <div class="feedbackTmpl>
        <p class="feedbackResponse"></p>
    </div>

   <!-- Add more templates if needed... -->
</div>

// Do your ajax call, and in the success response:
var feedbackTmpl = $('.feedbackTmpl', '#templates').clone();
$('.feedbackResponse', feedbackTmpl).text(response[0]['rating']);

// Boom! feedbackTmpl is ready to be inserted / appended
```

Answer (score -1):

As a general coding philosophy, I like to separate the data from the view. I see jquery as supplying the data, and I leave the displaying and styling of it to the view in the html page.

What I mean by this is you should create the html in your page (and not in the success function of your javascript code). You can use css to hide it until the data is ready. Then when you have the data, use javascript to inject it into the elements.

e.g.

Your html page should contain the full view/html

```
<div id="mycontent" class="hidden">
  <span id="name"></span> feedback form...
  ...
</div>

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Your javascript/jquery should just fetch the data and inject it

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function(response) {
    $('#name').text(response);
    ...
    $('#mycontent').show();
  }
})
```

I believe this is far better than creating/appending html in js code. If you must do that, reserve it for small html snippets, not entire html pages.